# How to expand height of Column wrapped by SingleChildScrollView properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to make a login form where the fields will be in a column of a specific width.
I wanted to be able to scroll the entire page when the window size is smaller.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          // height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,
          width: 500,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xfffee6dc),
              border: Border.all(
                  width: 0,
                  style: BorderStyle.none
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("TEST"),
              SizedBox(height: 50,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
}
}
```

This works, but when I maximize the window, the height of the container doesn't adjust to the size of the window, only to its children:

[image]

When I set the height to: **MediaQuery.of(context).size.height**
i's better,  but now when i shrink the window it throws me an error:
***A RenderFlex overflowed by ** pixels on the bottom*.**

[image]

Comment: use size config class for responsive ?

Answer (score 3):

If you like to adjust the height, it should be on top widget constraints .

```dart
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size.fromWidth(600)),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xfffee6dc),
              border: Border.all(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text("TEST"),
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ...[
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                  ],
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now it scrolls only container with form. I wanted to scroll whole page

Comment: use `body:SingleChildScrollView` instead of inner widget

Comment: yes, but then I back to the beginning. It's throw overfow error

Comment: You just want the white/powder color to the full height ?

Comment: Yes, And able to scroll whole page when window is smaller

Comment: yap, setting `body:SingleChildScrollView`  will work, can you include image what exactly you are trying to get

Comment: I already included images. On fullscreen I want white/powder color to the full height. But when I have smaller screen I want to scroll whole page. In my code it works but when I make screen smaller I get an error with overflow.

Comment: ok, try update snippet

Answer (score 0):

**you need to create new class name **sizeconfig****

Code of sizeconfig Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;
  static double? screenWidth;
  static double? screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;
  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData?.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData?.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData?.orientation;
    defaultSize = orientation == Orientation.landscape
        ? screenHeight! * 0.024
        : screenWidth! * 0.024;
  }
}
```

**Now you need to call this call inside build method:**

> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> SizeConfig().init(context);
> return Scaffold(

Now its Work Fine

```
**This is your Actual Class Code:**
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'confriguration/size_config.dart';
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Container(
          color:Colors.redAccent,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                // height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,
                width: SizeConfig.screenWidth! * 0.9,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xfffee6dc),
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 0,
                        style: BorderStyle.none
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("TEST"),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01,),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                    TextFormField(),
                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.01),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[Here is video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJHQnXc5CoEwfb6Z37Gnzq8LqSk1LxN9/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: It's fine for responsivity, but this not resolve my problem. In your solution, my container with form is still fitted do its children when window is maximalized. I would like expand this container in height to fit the window. And able to scroll whole page when window is smaller

Comment: then why you accept answer if your issue still not sloved

Comment: @pitcairn1987 its working Fine for me for all type of Windows

Comment: my mistake. I unaccepted already

Comment: @pitcairn1987 i paste video link check it out

Comment: Sorry. I complicated a problem too much. I've edited code and screens to show what i want to achieve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251565/discussion-between-pitcairn1987-and-mobin-ansar).